# How do I call code or respond to events in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How do I call code or respond to events in my native application with React Native? Can anyone explain with an example?

Comment: What have you tried so far. See part 3 of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean respond to events like when a user presses a button? If so check this section [Handling Touches](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/handling-touches).

When a user presses a button you can handle this way:

```
<Button 
  onPress={() => { /* This function will be called when the button is pressed */ }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Pedro has a great start. If it's a button, you do an `onPress` event. There are also events for things like text inputs.

```
<TextInput
     style={{height: 40}}
     placeholder="Type here to translate!"
     onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
/>
```

You can also call functions as state changes just like regular `React.js`.

Do you have an example of something specific you were looking to accomplish?